# applying a string function to a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this seems somewhat basic but after going through stackoverflow I couldn't seem to take everything answered and solve my problem.  so i'm working on my text processing skills.  I put car reviews in a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
    Review
0   :P I like you, Merc. You make me laugh! If Mat...
1   I am surprised that I did not find any discuss...
3   . . .let me see if I am following along correc...
4   . . .now hold on a minute. A "current" A6 4.2 ...
5   but has anyone noticed the front oh the new ac...
```

i wrote a function that takes a string as input and returns a value (in my case a sentiment score).  within my function, this value will be put in a newly created column.  the problem I obviously keep coming across is with the input - i get an expected string error.  with a dataframe, there are objects not strings.

the function is very long and works when a string is inputed.  here's a snippet of the function:  note that dataframe is titled edmunds.

```
def checker(b):
    word = 'ls'
    if stry.find(word) == -1:
        edmunds['ls'] = 0.0
    ...
    edmunds['ls'] = sum(o_list)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.  trying to wrap my head around if i should go from dataframe to list or if i could still work within pandas.

output would ideally look like:

```
Review                                                 ls
0   :P I like you, Merc. You make me laugh! If Mat...  0.4
1   I am surprised that I did not find any discuss...  0.5
3   . . .let me see if I am following along correc...  0.0
4   . . .now hold on a minute. A "current" A6 4.2 ...  1.0
5   but has anyone noticed the front oh the new ac...  -0.6
```

Comment: What have you tried here? You could apply your function row-wise which would look something like `df['ls'] = df.apply(lambda row: checker(x.Review), axis=1)` but ideally you want to vectorise your function so that it can be done on the whole column, at the moment your function looks incomplete so it's hard to suggest what improvements can be made

Comment: thats just the snippet of a very long function.  the concept is the same though.  it returns a number as an output given the input, which has to be a string.  the problem is that the dataframe does not contain strings - it contains objects.  for instance, when i try the above i get:  TypeError: ('expected string or buffer', u'occurred at index 0').  I'm trying to find a way to avoid that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a column `ls` from the column `Review`:

1. You need a function that takes *one* string and returns *one* number. Currently, the `checker` function doesn't do that, since it doesn't return anything (and also sets values inside `edmunds`, which is not necessary). Given how the function looks, you will probably want to end the function with a `return sum(o_list)`. And, to be clear, the input `b` must be a single string. One way to test this: you should be able to write `checker("hello")` and get a number back.
2. If you've written `checker` that way, then you can create `ls` easily:

   `edmunds['ls'] = edmunds.Review.apply(checker)`

In case you want to get more background on why Pandas works this way: The `apply` function is an example of [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) (a function over a list).